Can't import firebase admin in Node.js
Cannot find module 'firebase-admin' or its corresponding type declarations.
im trying to import admin from firebase :
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
i recieve this :
Cannot find module 'firebase-admin' or its corresponding type declarations.
im using Angular 17 and firebase 13.8.1
and using Node.js

please check if its installed, it should be present inside package.json and a folder inside node_modules!

This error message has come up quite regularly already: https://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+find+module+%27firebase-admin%27+or+its+corresponding+type+declarations. If you've tried all those things, edit your question to show how.
